# couldn't create the hash with option values and <div> text

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

*HTML Code:*

```
<div id="empid" title="Please first select a list to filter!"><input value="5418630" name="candidateprsonIds" type="checkbox">foo  <input value="6360899" name="candidateprsonIds" type="checkbox"> bar gui<input value="9556609" name="candidateprsonIds" type="checkbox"> bab </div>
```

Now I would like to get the below using selenium-webdriver as

```
[[5418630,foo],[6360899,bar gui],[9556609,bab]]
```

Can it be done?

I tried the below code:

```
driver.find_elements(:id,"filtersetedit_fieldNames").each do |x|

      puts x.text

end
```

But it is giving me the data as string `"foo bar gui bab"` on my console. Thus couldn't figure out - how to create such above expected `Hash`.

Any help on this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to get the text nodes like that would be to use the `execute_script` method.

The following script would give you the hash of option values and their following text.

```
#The div containing the checkboxes
checkbox_div = driver.find_element(:id => 'empid')

#Get all of the option values
option_values = checkbox_div.find_elements(:css => 'input').collect{ |x| x['value'] }
p option_values
#=> ["5418630", "6360899", "9556609"]

#Get all of the text nodes (by using javascript)
script = <<-SCRIPT
    text_nodes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments[0].childNodes.length; i++) {
        child = arguments[0].childNodes[i];
        if(child.nodeType == 3) {
            text_nodes.push(child.nodeValue);
        }
    }   
    return text_nodes
SCRIPT
option_text = driver.execute_script(script, checkbox_div)
#Tidy up the text nodes to get rid of blanks and extra white space
option_text.collect!(&:strip).delete_if(&:empty?)
p option_text
#=> ["foo", "bar gui", "bab"]

#Combine the two arrays to create a hash (with key being the option value)
option_hash = Hash[*option_values.zip(option_text).flatten]
p option_hash
#=> {"5418630"=>"foo", "6360899"=>"bar gui", "9556609"=>"bab"}
```

Comment: I am not getting the functionality means how the script will work? and your logic could you explain?

Comment: what these two are doing - `arguments[0].childNodes` and `child.nodeValue`. I don't know `javascript`. So if you give me a good link on this topic from where I can get to know how the logic works here,then I can also try these out. Again really this style gives me a good direction - trust me :)

Comment: `arguments` is an array of parameters passed to `execute_script`, in this case `arguments[0]` is the `checkbox_div`. The script is iterating over all child nodes of the `checkbox_div`, which includes the input elements and the text nodes. The `child.nodeType == 3` is checking if the child is a text node. If it is, `child.nodeValue` gives the actual text of the text node. (Hope that helps as I am not a javascript developer either.)

Comment: what this `*option_values` does?

Comment: `*` is the splat operator. It takes an the array produced by `option_values.zip(option_text).flatten` and makes each element an argument for `Hash[]`. In effect it is calling `Hash[['5418630', 'foo', ...]]`

Comment: @TheMiddleMan, what do you want me to see? There is already an answer to that question.

Comment: there was no answer of `part - II` which might reader missed to see.

Comment: Could you help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788241/how-to-get-the-reference-alive-to-the-older-one-when-there-is-a-second-exceptio)?

Comment: okay! Justin, as I believe and answer style of your answer,thus said. I will not ask you from now any.