# How to get the reference alive to the older one, when there is a second exception in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

```
begin
  raise "explosion"
rescue
  p $!
  raise "Are you mad"
  p $!
end

# #<RuntimeError: explosion>
# RuntimeError: Are you mad
#    from (irb):5:in `rescue in irb_binding'
#    from (irb):1
#    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

`$!` always holds only the *current* exception object reference.

***But is there any way to get a reference to the original exception object (here it is "explosion"), after another exception has been raised?*** <~~~ Here is my question.

Myself tried and reached to the answer,hope now it is more clearer to all who was in Smokey situation with my queries.

Comment: You are likely being down-voted since it is very unclear what you are asking for. It is a good idea to include a sample of what the desired outcome should be. In this case, what do you want to do with the original exception? You do not rescue the second exception, so why do you want the original exception again? When people have to guess what you might want, they will tend to downvote.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan Andrew Marshall's edit made your question clear, but now you added an extra paragraph that adds no new information, and made it unclear again with your broken English.

Comment: I have given the answer also.. Thanks to you people also.

Comment: @sawa Could you tell me what wrong now, I have posted my answer too. So what the confusion is now to understand what I was looking for? If still anything smoky,let me know.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan He’s saying it wasn’t confusing, but then you added more text that didn’t provide any more information, but *made* it confusing.

Comment: @jonathan Why my answer has been removed? - Where it has been written that `OP` can't put his answer himself?

Comment: @TheMiddleMan - If that was indeed an answer, we can undelete it, but it looked like an attempt to provide more detail to the question. Let me know if it is an actual answer and we can have it restored. You might want to add some language to the code to make it clear how this answers the question, though.

Comment: @BradLarson Yes, That is the answer. I have finally made. please restore it back.I will add the comments there - how it is the answer. If you a moderator please let me know, I have something to say you.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan - Okay, done. Again, a little language will need to be added there to explain that this is a legitimate answer and not an attempt to add more code to the question. We see a lot of people try to follow-on to their question in this way, which is why answers like this sometimes get flagged. It wasn't immediately clear to the moderator who handled this flag that your answer wasn't a failed attempt to edit the question. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan My mistake; I apologize. As Brad pointed out, we see posts like this all the time which serve to add additional code/details to the original question. You can help us avoid confusion by supplementing your code with an explanation of what it is and how it fixed your issue(s).

Answer (score 3):

Are you saying you want to have reference to the original exception when you rescue the second exception? If so, then you need to capture the original exception in a variable during the rescue. This is done by doing:

```
rescue StandardError => e
```

where StandardError can be any type of exception or omitted (in which case StandardError is the default).

For example, the code:

```
begin
    raise "original exception"
rescue StandardError => e
    puts "Original Exception:"
    puts $!
    puts e
    begin
        raise "second exception"
    rescue
        puts "Second Exception:"
        puts $!
        puts e      
    end
end
```

Gives the output:

```
Original Exception:
original exception
original exception
Second Exception:
second exception
original exception
```

As you can see `e` has stored the original exception for use after the second exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyError < StandardError
attr_reader :original
def initialize(msg, original=$!)
super(msg)
@original = original;
end
end
begin
    begin
    raise "explosion"
    rescue => error
    raise MyError, "Are you mad"
    end
rescue => error
puts "Current failure: #{error.inspect}"
puts "Original failure: #{error.original.inspect}"
end
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Current failure: #<MyError: Are you mad>
Original failure: #<RuntimeError: explosion>
=> nil
```